# How to convert string to uniqueidentifier?

Tags: c#, string, uniqueidentifier

I want to insert a string into a table as a uniqueidentifier type. But when I insert it to the database, it throws an error. How can i convert a `string` to a `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: So... is dsfdsf just a keyboard cough or does it mean something?

Comment: I guess he me means "in the format like dsfdsf-dfdsf-dfgdsfg" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try:

```
new Guid("string to convert");
```

But the string will need to be in Guid format already.

Answer (score 7):

In .Net 4, there's a `Guid.TryParse(string, out Guid)` which returns `bool` on success.

Comment: Good one. This is the safest option

Answer (score 3):

This is a safe way to attempt parsing a `string` into a `Guid`. In my example, `input` is a `string` variable from the user:

```
var myGuid = new Guid();
if (Guid.TryParse(input, out myGuid)) {
    // Parsed OK
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use one of these:

```
Guid.TryParse
```

or

```
Guid.TryParseExact
```